# onCreateViewHolder is never called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am trying to use recyclerView which is inside a fragment.This is fragment is nested inside the viewPager.

```
public class UniversityDetail extends Fragment {

RecyclerView universityDetailView;

//need to set Adapter

public static UniversityDetail newInstance(){
    return new UniversityDetail();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_university_lsit,container,false);
    universityDetailView = (RecyclerView)view;
    setupViews();
    return view;
}


private void setupViews(){
    //set the adapter
    UniversityDetailAdapter detailAdapter = new UniversityDetailAdapter(new ArrayList<UniversityDetails>());
    universityDetailView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerListDecorater(getActivity()));
    universityDetailView.setAdapter(detailAdapter);
    universityDetailView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    universityDetailView.setHasFixedSize(false);
}

public RecyclerView getRecyclerView(){
    return this.universityDetailView;
   }
}
```

This is the fragment which i want to be inside the viewPager.It returns a recyclerView from onCreateView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

fragment_university_lsit.xml

recyclerView uses below adapter.

```
public class UniversityDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<UniversityDetails> universityDetails;
private static Map<String,String> admissionRecommendation;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((DetailHolder)holder).bind(universityDetails.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return universityDetails.size();
}

public UniversityDetailAdapter(List<UniversityDetails> details){
    this.universityDetails = details;
}
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType){
    Log.d("CreateUniveristyDetail", "onCreateViewHolder: detail called");
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment,parent,false);
    return new DetailHolder(itemView);
   }
}
```

DetailHolder is the class extends ReyclerView.ViewHolder and its implementation is irrelevant here.

The adapter list is upated from handler and notifyDataSetChanged()

```
private void setup(){
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
      @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message){
          if(message.what == ConnectionHandler.DETAILMSG){
              Log.d("detail handle message", "handleMessage: Called");
              List<UniversityDetails> details = (List<UniversityDetails>)message.obj;
              UniversityDetailAdapter adapter = (UniversityDetailAdapter)universityDetail.getRecyclerView().getAdapter();
              adapter.addAll(details);
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              Log.d("size", "handleMessage: " + adapter.getItemCount());
          }
      }
    };
}
```

Fragment is created in activity..

```
 private void setupNavigation(){
    ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    universityDetail = UniversityDetail.newInstance();
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(universityDetail);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    //setup the fragment transaction.

    headerTab.setViewPager(mViewPager,0);
    //no need to add to back stack
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.view_pager,universityDetail);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Implementation of DetailHolder

```
 public  class DetailHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    CardView admissionGeneral;
    public View root;

    public DetailHolder (View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        root = itemView;
        admissionGeneral = (CardView)root.findViewById(R.id.admission_general);
    }

    public void bind(UniversityDetails detail){

        Log.d("detail bind", "bind: binding to recyclerView");

        }
    }
```

here the log of adapter.getItemCount(); return 3; thats means something is being added and onCreateViewHolder is supposed to be called but it never is.

The weird thing is i have implemented another recyclerAdapter is the sameProject and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: If it's never called, then you never make an instance of the Fragment. If you think you are, please show that code.

Comment: i have crated it in activity and called when activity is created..

Comment: So, you're saying that onCreateView is not called, yet you are able to get the RecyclerView adapter and add data to it...  Sounds like it is being called. Try adding a Log statement in there

Comment: i added the log statement onCreateView it is never called.Further i checked the size of the list added by call Adapter.addAll() which was 3. That means somethings is thrown,of course notifyDataSetChanged() is also called.However onCreateView is not called even if i added items in the list of the adapter.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about the Fragment `onCreateView` or the adapter `onCreateViewHolder`? The Fragment one is definitely being called

Comment: Have you tried to `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailHolder>`?

Comment: I am sorry i was talking about onCreateViewHolder i am extremely sorry for that ?

Comment: DetailHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder.Doi need to show its implementation??

Comment: It may be useful to see, sure

Answer (score 0):

This problem would be easier to answer if you could show how the `universityDetail` was assigned from whatever class contains the `Handler` usage.

It's also not clear how `message.obj` is able to be cast to a List.

I believe you are using a different instance of the Fragment there than the one that you want to update.

---

So, you know this line is good

```
List<UniversityDetails> details = (List<UniversityDetails>)message.obj;
```

because you see 3 in the output when you do this

```
Log.d("size", "handleMessage: " + adapter.getItemCount());
```

Now, these lines could likely be the problem.

```
UniversityDetailAdapter adapter = (UniversityDetailAdapter)universityDetail.getRecyclerView().getAdapter();
adapter.addAll(details);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Firstly, there is no `addAll` method to `RecyclerView.Adapter`. So I'm not sure how that compiled. Anyways...

Try to keep cross-class references to a minimum. Here, we expose only the method to add the details rather than the entire RecyclerView.

Then, for RecyclerViews, you should notify only the data that was inserted rather than all of it using `notifyItemRangeInserted`

```
public class UniversityDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView universityDetailView;
    private UniversityDetailAdapter detailAdapter;

    private List<UniversityDetails> details = new ArrayList<UniversityDetails>();

    ...

    public void setupViews() {
        detailAdapter = new UniversityDetailAdapter(details);
        // etc...
    }

    public void addDetails(List<UniversityDetails> details) {
        int curSize = detailAdapter.getItemCount();
        this.details.addAll(details);
        detailAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(curSize, details.size()); 
    }
}
```

And then just use the instance of your Fragment

```
  if(message.what == ConnectionHandler.DETAILMSG){
      Log.d("detail handle message", "handleMessage: Called");
      List<UniversityDetails> details = (List<UniversityDetails>) message.obj;
      universityDetail.addDetails(details);
```

Another recommendation would be to use the correct generic type for the holder class to avoid unnecessary casts.

```
public class UniversityDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailHolder>
```